# Compare strings from two tables SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, join, string-searching

I'm using these two tables in a SQL Server 2014 database:

```
CREATE TABLE #FORMULAS 
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DataSourceAddress] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL
)

CREATE INDEX [IX_FORMULAS] 
ON #FORMULAS ([DataSourceAddress] ASC)

CREATE TABLE #PARAMETERS
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Datetime] DateTime NULL,
    [ParameterName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Value] float NULL
)

CREATE INDEX [IX_PARAMETERS] 
ON #PARAMETERS([ParameterName] ASC)

INSERT INTO #FORMULAS ([DataSourceAddress], [Description])
VALUES ('(parameter1+parameter2+parameter3)/3', 'Formula description 1'),
       ('parameter4', 'Formula description 2'),
       ('(parameter5*1000)', 'Formula description 3');

INSERT INTO #PARAMETERS ([Datetime], [ParameterName], [Value])
VALUES ('2016-01-26 11:40:00.000', 'parameter1', 1),
       ('2016-01-26 11:40:00.000', 'parameter2', 2),
       ('2016-01-26 11:40:00.000', 'parameter3', 3),
       ('2016-01-26 11:40:00.000', 'parameter4', 4),
       ('2016-01-26 11:40:00.000', 'parameter5', 5),
       ('2016-01-26 11:40:00.000', 'parameter6', 6),
       ('2016-01-26 11:44:00.000', 'parameter1', 1),
       ('2016-01-26 11:44:00.000', 'parameter2', 2),
       ('2016-01-26 11:44:00.000', 'parameter3', 3),
       ('2016-01-26 11:44:00.000', 'parameter4', 4),
       ('2016-01-26 11:44:00.000', 'parameter5', 5),
       ('2016-01-26 11:44:00.000', 'parameter6', 6);
```

I want to select the parameters of the table `#FORMULAS` that match with the column `[ParameterName]` of the table `#PARAMETERS`.

For example, take the value '(parameter1+parameter2+parameter3)/3' of the table `#FORMULAS` and receive all the rows of the table `#PARAMETERS` that contains `'parameter1','parameter2','parameter3'`.

I'm using the following select:

```
SELECT  
    A.[Datetime],
    A.[ParameterName],
    B.[Description],
    A.[Value]
FROM   
    #PARAMETERS A
JOIN 
    #FORMULAS B ON CHARINDEX(A.[ParameterName], B.[DataSourceAddress]) > 0
```

The `#PARAMETERS` table has more than 160000 rows (with 1174 unique `ParameterNames`), `#FORMULAS` has 3283 rows. The query takes a lot of time to finish, more than 10 minutes.

Is there a faster way to do the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcard matching strings with good performance will always be tricky, but here's a best-effort attempt.

First off, your indexing can be improved. The index on #PARAMETERS only includes the actual `ParameterName` column, which is fine if you need a list of parameters, but whenever you need any other column, the index will be useless to SQL Server, and it'll revert to scanning the entire table instead. I would propose fixing this by changing the index to a clustered index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PARAMETERS]
    ON #PARAMETERS (ParameterName, [Datetime])
    WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON);     -- Remove this row if the index doesn't already exist.
```

Clustered indexes include every column in the table, which automatically makes a clustered index a [covering indexes](http://sqlsunday.com/2013/02/24/covering-indexes/).

From here, I've updated your query to do three things:

- Collect each *unique* parameter in #PARAMETERS.
- For each unique parameter, find matching formulas in #FORMULAS. This is the expensive part, and no index will really improve this search because the search condition (LIKE) is not [sargable](http://sqlsunday.com/2014/01/19/sargable-expression-performance/). This means that, index or not, SQL Server will go through each and every row in the table (a so-called scan), for every parameter.
- Finally, join #PARAMETERS to get all the dates and values. This is a relatively cheap and efficient operation. This is where the modified index on #PARAMETERS helps.

Here's the resulting query:

```
SELECT  A.[Datetime],
        p.[ParameterName],
        B.[Description],
        A.[Value]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ParameterName FROM #PARAMETERS) p
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM #FORMULAS B WITH (FORCESCAN)
    WHERE B.DataSourceAddress LIKE N'%'+p.ParameterName+N'%') AS B
INNER JOIN #PARAMETERS AS A ON
    p.ParameterName=A.ParameterName;
```

I added `WITH (FORCESCAN)` to eliminate key lookups. You can try the query with or without this hint.

If I had a lot more time to work on this and it was a super-critical query, I would probably (a) remodel the tables and/or (b) consider storing the data in #FORMULAS as XML data and add XML indexes, which would eliminate the LIKE match.

Footnote: Text matching like you do here (`LIKE` and `CHARINDEX` are pretty much the same here) will include formulas with the parameters "parameter10" and "parameter11" even when you're just searching for "parameter1".

Comment: I have a problem with similar parameters using 'LIKE' clause. For example, If you add the row '('2016-01-26 11:40:00.000','param',7)' in the #PARAMETERS TABLE, you'll see that the result returns rows with the parameter 'param' but there isn't parameters named 'param' in the #FORMLAS table. Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I think that replace 'WHERE B.DataSourceAddress LIKE N'%'+p.ParameterName+N'%')' for 'WHERE (B.[DataSourceAddress] = p.ParameterName 
    OR  B.[DataSourceAddress] like N'%[^0-9a-z]'+p.ParameterName+N'[^0-9a-z]%'))' could be a possible solution...

Comment: It'll produce exactly the same results, but the `OR` will complicate the query and make it more expensive.

Comment: To solve the wildcard problem, you would need to establish a strict naming convention for your parameters and then build that into the wildcard pattern. For instance, `LIKE '%parameter[0-9][^0-9]%'.

Comment: @JosepBacardit: An alternative could be to specify all possible delimiters on both sides of the parameter name: `… LIKE N'%[+-*/()]'+p.ParameterName+N'[+-*/()]%'`. And to account for the names exactly at the beginning and exactly at the end of the source string, just make sure they are delimited on both sides: `'+' + B.DataSourceAddress + '+' LIKE …`.

Comment: @AndriyM, yes. Just remember to escape the minus sign. :)

Comment: True, or you could move it to the beginning, for instance: `[-+*/()]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my case I have used the this where clause `WHERE B.DataSourceAddress LIKE N'%'+p.ParameterName+N'%')' for 'WHERE (B.[DataSourceAddress] = p.ParameterName OR B.[DataSourceAddress] like N'%[^0-9a-z]'+p.ParameterName+N'[^0-9a-z]%'))` and it works.